# Qt: slot not called on manual function call

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a checkbox with a slot called

```
void MainWindow::on_checkBoxPhaseUnwrap_stateChanged(int state)
```

This is automatically connected.

The constructor of MainWindow is like this

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupWidgets();
}
```

In `setupWidgets` I set the value of the checkbox

```
ui->checkBoxPhaseUnwrap->setChecked(true);
```

However the slot is not called, and thus the data base in the background not updated.

Once the window is shown I can click on the checkbox and the slot is called as usual. Why is it not called when I call `setChecked` Note: In the gui designer the default value is already `checked`. Is this the reason?

Comment: Does calling the function with the argument false trigger the slot?

Comment: Could you show us how you connect?

Comment: There is no connect from ymself. This is done with in Qt automatically.

Comment: Indeed with false the slot is called.

Answer (score 2):

> In the gui designer the default value is already checked. Is this the reason?

Yes [void QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged)

> This signal is emitted whenever the checkbox's state changes, i.e., whenever the user checks or unchecks it.

That means it is not emitted if you try to change state from `Qt::Checked` to `Qt::Checked`.

**Solution** would be to emit signal yourself:

In `setupWidgets` add

```
emit ui->checkBoxPhaseUnwrap->stateChanged(Qt::Checked);
```